# How can I correctly implement tkinter's .after() method in the context of my program?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am creating a simple GUI program that utilizes Python and Tkinter to log the time/date when a user presses a button on the interface (by appending information to a .txt file), as well as sending an e-mail to a list of addresses informing the recipients that the log has been updated.

The program has three main frames/screens that I would like the user to navigate through. The navigation between the screens should be time-based. In other words, I would like the user to be redirected from the main screen to a secondary screen upon the press of a Tkinter button (which I have already established using the 'command' argument of the Tkinter widgets), and then be automatically redirected back to the main screen after a 5-second time delay.

I understand that using `time.sleep()` is not encouraged in GUI programs. However, I have had some trouble implementing Tkinter's `.after()` method, and haven't quite been able to achieve my desired result.

I have attached a simplified example of my program code that models my problem:

```
import tkinter as tk


class mainApplication(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (MainScreen, AcknowledgeScreen):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(MainScreen)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class MainScreen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Press Button to Log Time")
        label.pack()

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Confirm", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(AcknowledgeScreen))
        button.pack()


class AcknowledgeScreen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Logging Completed. Please Wait.")
        label.pack()

        # The implementation below is giving me trouble.

        self.after(5000, controller.show_frame(MainScreen))


root = mainApplication()
root.mainloop()
```

The other solutions I have attempted (for the line of interest) include:

```
# Attempt 1
self.after(5000, controller.show_frame(MainScreen))  # This code waits 5 seconds before opening the GUI window; does not redirect back to MainScreen from AcknowledgeScreen.

# Attempt 2
root.after(5000, controller.show_frame(MainScreen))  # This code throws an error 'NameError: name 'root' is not defined.

# Attempt 3
label.after(5000, controller.show_frame(MainScreen))  # This code waits 5 seconds before opening the GUI window; does not redirect back to MainScreen from AcknowledgeScreen.
```

Unfortunately, I have never been exposed to object-oriented programming before beginning with Tkinter, so I believe that my errors might be due to a fundamental misunderstanding of how OOP works. Nonetheless, I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction or clarify my errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mainApplication`, both screens are initialized and their classes used for dictionary keys mapping to their instances.

From the ordering of your operations, the `MainScreen` should be raised in the stacking order after `AcknowledgeScreen` is displayed.

This operation shouldn't live in the `AcknowledgeScreen.__init__` except you initialize the screens at the time they are needed.

You want to move this to `MainScreen`. You can refactor the `MainScreen` the following way.

```py
class MainScreen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Press Button to Log Time")
        label.pack()
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Confirm", command=self.confirm)
        button.pack()

    def confirm(self):
        self.controller.show_frame(AcknowledgeScreen)
        self.after(5000, self.back)

    def back(self):
        self.controller.show_frame(MainScreen)
```

Answer (score 0):

`after()` (like `bind()` and `command=`) needs `callback` - it means function name without `()` and without arguments.

Use `lambda`

```
  self.after(5000, lambda:controller.show_frame(MainScreen))
```

---

But I see different problem.

When you run program then it creates instances of all frames in `mainApplication.__init__` so it runs also  `AcknowledgeScreen.__init__` at start - and it runs `after()` at start. It doesn't wait for your click.

BTW: because frames are create inside `mainApplication.__init__` so they can't use `root` which will be created after `mainApplication.__init__` ends its job.

You would have to add some parts in methods and run everytime when you click button.

```
class MainScreen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Press Button to Log Time")
        label.pack()

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Confirm", command=self.change)
        button.pack()

    def change(self):
        self.controller.show_frame(AcknowledgeScreen)
        self.controller.frames[AcknowledgeScreen].change_after()      

class AcknowledgeScreen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Logging Completed. Please Wait.")
        label.pack()

    def change_after(self):
        # The implementation below is giving me trouble.

        #both works
        #root.after(5000, lambda:self.controller.show_frame(MainScreen))
        self.after(5000, lambda:self.controller.show_frame(MainScreen))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this code:

```
self.after(5000, controller.show_frame(MainScreen))
```

The above code does exactly the same thing as this:

```
result = controller.show_frame(MainScreen)
self.after(5000, result)
```

Notice what happens? The function `controller.show_frame(MainScreen)` executes immediately, rather than being executed by `after`.

Instead, you need to give `after` a *callable* -- roughly speaking, a reference to a function. If that function requires additional arguments, you can add those arguments when calling `after`:

```
self.after(5000, controller.show_frame, MainScreen)
```

The above code tells `after` to run `controller.show_frame` in five seconds, and to pass it the argument `MainScreen` when it is called.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Bryan. This is a great explanation of how the `after` method operates. That being said, I tested your implementation and ran into the following situation: when the program loaded and I pressed the 'confirm' button, the `AcknowledgeScreen` frame appeared for five seconds and then returned back to the `MainScreen` frame. However, if I press the button _again_ while the window is still open, `AcknowledgeScreen` does not return to `MainScreen`, but rather, hangs at `AcknowledgeScreen` indefinitely. Do you have an idea what might be causing this?